# Java basics - conditions

Tags: java

Can anyone explain how it return "C" and not report error in "b = false"?

```
class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean b;
        if (b = false) {System.out.print("A");
        } else if (b) {System.out.print("B");
        } else if (!b) {System.out.print("C");
        } else {System.out.print("D");}
    }
 }
```

Thank for helping me

Comment: Why would it report an error for you assigning a value to a variable?

Comment: Comparison uses `==` not `=` , so `if (b == false)` or `if (!b)`

Comment: `= vs ==` ......

Comment: Look at your first `if` and how you are attempting to check for equality.

Comment: @david I don’t think that’s clear at all. Why would that report an ‘error’ rather than just print A. It seems the user is more questioning why the assignment evaluates to false.

Answer (score 0):

`b = false` assigns `false` to `b` and returns `false`. Therefore the `if (b = false)` condition is `false`, and the `if (b)` condition is also `false`.

The first condition which is `true` is `if (!b)`, which results in "C" being printed.

Answer (score 0):

```
class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean b;
        if (b = false) {System.out.print("A"); //Assign false to b, gets false
        } else if (b) {System.out.print("B");  //b is now false
        } else if (!b) {System.out.print("C"); //NOT b is true
        } else {System.out.print("D");}        //never gets to this block
    }
 }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.